# How to slowing down my query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am new in database sql. I know that indexes make query faster. But I want to learn the ways of making query slowing down without dropping or creating objects.

```
    create index ind1 on students_2(surname);
        select * from students s1, students_2 s2
    where s1.name1=substr(s2.surname,1,5) and s1.dep=s2.dep and 
    s1.dep in ('Econ','Law')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can embed a sleep into any expression.

```
select * 
from students s1 
join students_2 s2 
  on s1.name1=substr(s2.surname,1,5) and s1.dep=s2.dep
where s1.dep in ('Econ','Law')
  and sleep(0.1)=0;
```

This will add a 0.1 second sleep every time a row is examined. The [sleep() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep) normally returns 0.

P.S.: Please use proper `JOIN` syntax instead of obsolete "comma" joins.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, and probably the easiest one, would be to use an [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to ignore the indexes you have, like this:

```
select * 
from 
  students s1
ignore index ind1
```

Alternatively, you can try to slown down the query (more) by makeing it more complex. 
The query below is modified a bit, especially the part that checks for the name. Instead of just matching by name, it matches two parts of the name. Because of the second condition, any index on `s1.name1` cannot be efficiently used, and MySQL has to do a lot of string manipulation:

```
select * 
from 
  students s1, students_2 s2
where 
  substr(s1.name1, 1, 1) = substr(s2.surname, 1, 1) and 
  substr(s1.name1, 2) = substr(s2.surname, 2, 5) and 
  s1.dep = s2.dep and 
  s1.dep in ('Econ','Law')
```

Just like with adding indexes, forcefully not using indexes will also have varying results. Query results might still be cached, and even without indexes, a query can be pretty fast.